# how to remember login status in spring-authorization-server1.1?

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I run this [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples)

I found that each request for authorization will resets the cookie。
[image]

So I need to keep logging in repeatedly, how do I remember my login status?